# How can I automatically create backreferences in RealmObjects when deserialized from JSON?

Tags: android, json, database, realm

when I implemented my DB with OrmLite, I was able to let backreferences be created automatically. For example, imagine a class A which has a reference to a list of objects of class B and Class B has a reference back to that specific object of class A. With Gson/OrmLite, when parsing the following JSON it would create a obejct of class A with a ForeignCollection of Class B objects and for every class B object it would create a reference to the class A object (if I am not mistaking anything here). Take the following json (representing an object of Class A):

`{
  "id":5,
  "objectsOfTypeB": [
    {
     "id":2,
     "name":"pete"
    }, 
    {
     "id":4,
     "name":"mathew"
    }]
}`

Now I would like to do the same with Realm. Is it somehow possible to create a backreference for nested objects? Maybe hook into the object-creation process and set the reference manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian from Realm here.

The core database support the notion of backlinks, which is what you are looking for, but they havn't been exposed in the Java API yet. This means that until we can add support for them, you will manually  have to create and maintain these relationships. That can only be done if you do the import manually as it is not possible to hook into the current JSON import.